# xml file in soap

Tags: web-services, soap

My last question about soap series :)

Now, i have xml file which must be send to the soap web service.

Do i have to attach it as file to request OR send as method parameter in request?

What is the best approach? By the way size of file is variable.it can be reached 10mb

sometimes.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you refer to it as a file? Is it a file on disk somewhere? Are there other parameters to the web service, or is the "file" the only payload? Also, what platform, technology and version are you using? .NET vs. Java? WCF vs. ASMX? .NET 2.0 vs. .NET 3.5 SP1?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into soap with attachments, or alternatively you could serialise it as byte array and send it as a parameter.